# I want to disable iphone screen activation when plugging in a charger

Tags: iphone, battery, screen, charging

I want to use a low power, ultra light weight solar charger for a three week backpacking trip. But I have heard that any shadows will lower the output causing the phone repeatedly start/stop charging. On an iPhone, this causes the screen to repeatedly activate for a few seconds to say "charging started". This uses a lot of power I can't afford to waste! Can I stop the iPhone from waking up the screen when its battery begins to charge? iPhone 5, iOS 9.3.5.

Comment: I recommend using the Solartab (a solar charger with a built-in battery) to prevent repeated starting/stopping of charging. It's a more reliable charger (meaning no more screen off/ons) and it's better for the iPhone's battery too! A similar effect could also be achieved by charging a Mophie portable battery pack (or another that allows charging and discharging simultaneously) from your solar charger and your iPhone from that Mophie.

Comment: What happens when iPhone was switched off before charging?

Comment: Can you set display light to manual and keep it lowest this way?

Comment: At least there's the low light mode. I always use in darkest nights.

Comment: Are you willing to jailbreak? If not, there is no native way to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

**There is no native way to achieve this. Here are some alternatives:**

1. Low-light mode. Go to Settings - General - Accessibility - Zoom - Zoom Filter - Low Light. Enable zoom, double-tap the screen with three fingers, and you now have extra low light mode.

2. Buy a solar charger with a built-in battery

3. Jailbreak. There are many tweaks on this, but I will not list them here as I advise against jailbreaking.